# Content Elements: The session id is too long or contains illegal characters

Tags: content-elements

All of the sudden today, I getting the following error msg on my site and in EE install

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: session_start(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,'
Filename: content_elements/ft.content_elements.php
Line Number: 38

Has anyone run in this before?

Comment: Quite the unusual error. Try clearing your cookies. Verify the files are all up-to-date as well.

Comment: Getting the same error now for a couple weeks. No one else running into this issue?

Comment: I never could get it figured out so i disabled the plugin.